# Queries regarding email-to-case automation(using google group) and auto-response rule

Tags: email2case, case-auto-response

1. If I add the salesforce email service address to the google group(techsupport@xyz.com), then the salesforce email address will receive all the mails that gets sent to the google group. So there will be no need for setting up forwarding of emails in a particular group member mail that was initially used to generate the salesforce email id. Then is it still necessary to include the routing address in email-to-case?
   (Right now, I'm actually forwarding the emails from a group member email id to the salesforce generated email id.)
2. My other query is, why do I need to enable IMAP as stated in this help article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000170989&type=1
3. When an auto-response is sent to the person who sent a mail to our support mail, the response header is of the format :  via xxxxxxxx.xxxxx.xxxx.xxx.salesforce.com and I can't view those mails in the sent mail box for supportnoreply@xyz.com. Why is it?
4. If I send an email to the techsupport@xyz.com(google group) from its member email where the forwarding to salesforce email id has been set up, then the auto-response rule will send the email back to that member email and shouldn't another case be created again, triggering an infinite loop of automated case creation?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the first 3, but regarding 4: yes, auto responses can trigger an infinite loop.  What I tend to do is create an inbox rule that deletes auto-responses so they don't end up being redirected to Salesforce & creating cases.